# Trigger Update after Insert with If Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cobaEditPegawai1 AFTER INSERT ON detail_pemangku_jabatan
FOR EACH ROW
IF detail_pemangku_jabatan.nip_pemangku = "0" THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE ekinerja_tempsimpeg.lap_bagan SET  ID_Peg = "" WHERE KUnKer = NEW.kode_jabatan;
ELSE
    UPDATE ekinerja_tempsimpeg.lap_bagan SET  ID_Peg = NEW.id_pegawai WHERE KUnKer = NEW.kode_jabatan;
END IF ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

on my app, its not work.

> message : "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'detail_pemangku_jabatan' in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intend:

```
IF new.nip_pemangku = 0 THEN
```